# Changing HTML img src on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I change an image dependent on scroll height with the image inside of the html?

Current

```
<div id="astronaut">
                <img src="img/astronaut.svg" alt="Astronaut Static" />
</div>
```

Desired on scroll

```
<div id="astronaut">
                <img src="img/astronaut-travel.svg" alt="Astronaut Travelling" />
</div>
```

Current CSS (centering image)

```
#astronaut {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Current JavaScript (changing the position of image to fixed on desired height)

```
window.onscroll = function(){

   if(window.scrollY >= 1000) { 
      document.getElementById('astronaut').setAttribute(
      "style", "position:fixed;");
   }else {
      document.getElementById('astronaut').setAttribute(
      "style", "");
    }

};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onscroll = function(){

   if(window.scrollY >= 1000) { 
      document.getElementById("astronaut").src="../img/astronaut-travel.svg";
   }else {
      document.getElementById("astronaut").src="../img/astronaut.svg";
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
window.onscroll = function(){

  if(window.scrollY >= 100) { 
      document.getElementById('astronaut').setAttribute(
      "style", "position:fixed;");
       $('#astronaut img').attr('src', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/37/Small-world-network-example.png/220px-Small-world-network-example.png')
   }else {
      document.getElementById('astronaut').setAttribute(
      "style", "");
    }
};
});
</script>
 <style>
  #astronaut {
  background:red;
height:1050px;
  z-index: 100;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="astronaut">
     <img src="http://www.mathcurve.com/polyedres/archimedien/pavage-sphere-dodecaedreTronque.jpg" alt="Astronaut Static" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```